# iOS 14 Advertising tracking and Facebook SDK 13.2

Tags: ios, swift

Hi I was wondering what is the correct way to do this. Facebook documentation is kind of misleading. On Meta for developers website on the page titled [Advertising Tracking Enabled](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-events/guides/advertising-tracking-enabled/) they say you should use snippet

```
Settings.shared.isAdvertiserTrackingEnabled = true
```

But on the [Get Started – iOS](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-events/getting-started-app-events-ios) near the bottom of the document there is title Get Device Consent. There they also mention

```
Settings.shared.isAutoLogAppEventsEnabled = false
Settings.shared.isAdvertiserIDCollectionEnabled = true
```

1. So should I also set these two to false if the user declines to share data?
2. Also if I edit my Info.plist file and add lines

   FacebookAutoLogAppEventsEnabled

   FacebookAdvertiserIDCollectionEnabled

as the Getting started advises won't this be disabled every time I launch the app? I would be overwritten to true only one time when iOS native AppTracking dialog would show up and user would click Allow. Am I right?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I also exactly had the same question when I was integrating Facebook SDK.
I ended up solving problem like this.

1. initialize Facebook SDK with everything false

```
func application(
        _ application: UIApplication,
        didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
    ) -> Bool {
... 
   // initialize Facebook SDK 
   ApplicationDelegate.shared.application(application, 
   didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
   Settings.isAutoLogAppEventsEnabled = false
   Settings.setAdvertiserTrackingEnabled(false)
   Settings.isAdvertiserIDCollectionEnabled = false
}
```

2. Update Facebook SDK Setting after showing prompt

```
ATTrackingManager.requestTrackingAuthorization { [weak self] status in
   let isConsented = status == .authorized
   Settings.isAutoLogAppEventsEnabled = isConsented
   Settings.setAdvertiserTrackingEnabled(isConsented)
   Settings.isAdvertiserIDCollectionEnabled = isConsented
}
```

3. Like you said prompt will appear only once, I check the authorization status every time when app becomes active. (I used didBecomeActiveNotification)

```
func checkATTStatus() {
        log.debug("current ATT status: \(ATTrackingManager.trackingAuthorizationStatus)")
        let isConsented = ATTrackingManager.trackingAuthorizationStatus == .authorized
        Settings.isAutoLogAppEventsEnabled = isConsented
        Settings.setAdvertiserTrackingEnabled(isConsented)
        Settings.isAdvertiserIDCollectionEnabled = isConsented
    }
```

I'm not 100% sure about this because I am still in testing stage (also
Facebook's test event page is not working properly).

Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: This should be `Settings.shared` since SDK version 13.0. That being said, I couldn't make this work, I'm presuming it has something to do with when in the lifecycle it's being set. I just opted for setting it in the Info.plist instead.